# JavaScript - Variable changing randomly at times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I'm a Japanese language graduate experiment with JavaScript for a project and the first thing I tried to create was this simple JavaScript based FlashCard game.

It basically generates an array of random numbers and uses this random numbers to fill the divs with 6 possible choices using jQuery. Then it randomly picks one number of the said array and makes it the correct choice. Finally, it reads the user choice (using jQuery text method) and do the expected output based on that.

The flashcard is running almost fine. The issue is that at times the variable `pontos` (points) is summed twice when the if statement returns true. I don't really know why. I also noticed that at times the script calls the function `jogar()` even if the select text is false.

As I'm really unskilled with programming, I'd like to apologize beforehand for the messy code and the most likely amateur error that I'm comiting.

Would any of you be so kind and help me with this question?

```
    var hiragana, jogar, romaji, pontos;
pontos = 0;

hiragana = ["あ", "か", "さ", "た", "な", "は", "ま", "や", "ら", "わ", "ん", "い", "き", "し", "ち", "に", "ひ", "み", "り", "う", "く", "す", "つ", "ぬ", "ふ", "む", "ゆ", "る", "え", "け", "せ", "て", "ね", "へ", "め", "れ", "お", "こ", "そ", "と", "の", "ほ", "も", "よ", "ろ", "を"];

romaji = ["A", "Ka", "Sa", "Ta", "Na", "Ha", "Ma", "Ya", "Ra", "Wa", "N", "I", "Ki", "Shi", "Chi", "Ni", "Hi", "Mi", "Ri", "U", "Ku", "Su", "Tsu", "Nu", "Fu", "Mu", "Yu", "Ru", "E", "Ke", "Se", "Te", "Ne", "He", "Me", "Re", "O", "Ko", "So", "To", "No", "Ho", "Mo", "Yo", "Ro", "Wo"];



jogar = function() {
    var arr, kpergunta, correto_secreto, found, hiragana_1, hiragana_2, hiragana_3, hiragana_4, hiragana_5, hiragana_6, i, pergunta, randomnumber, pontuacao;
    $("div.kana").css("color", "white");
    pontuacao = "Acertos: " + pontos;
    $("#pontuacao").html(pontuacao);
    arr = [];
    while (arr.length < 6) {
        randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * hiragana.length);
        found = false;
        i = 0;
        while (i < arr.length) {
            if (arr[i] === randomnumber) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (!found) {
            arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
        }
    }
    hiragana_1 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[0]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana1").html(hiragana_1);
    hiragana_2 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[1]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana2").html(hiragana_2);
    hiragana_3 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[2]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana3").html(hiragana_3);
    hiragana_4 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[3]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana4").html(hiragana_4);
    hiragana_5 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[4]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana5").html(hiragana_5);
    hiragana_6 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[5]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana6").html(hiragana_6);

    kpergunta = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    correto_secreto = hiragana[kpergunta];

    pergunta = "<h2>" + "Escolha o kana correto:" + " " + romaji[kpergunta] + "</h2>";
    $("#correto").html(pergunta);

    $("div.kana").click(function() {
        var text, id, correto;
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        text = $(this).text();
        if (text === correto_secreto) {
            $("#" + id).css("color", "green");
            pontos += 1;
            setTimeout(jogar, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#" + id).css("color", "red");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: To make it easier for you guys, I created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cypx77hh/embedded/result/ -- I hope it helps.

Comment: It is because you subscribe click function on div.kana multiple times. Notice that you put setTimeOut(jogar, 1000). This function would subscribe again the click function for div.kana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to try this:
To put the `div.cana` click function subscription outside `jogar`.
Please let me know if this solves your problem. Thanks

```
jogar = function() {
    var arr, kpergunta, correto_secreto, found, hiragana_1, hiragana_2, hiragana_3, hiragana_4, hiragana_5, hiragana_6, i, pergunta, randomnumber, pontuacao;
    $("div.kana").css("color", "white");
    pontuacao = "Acertos: " + pontos;
    $("#pontuacao").html(pontuacao);
    arr = [];
    while (arr.length < 6) {
        randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * hiragana.length);
        found = false;
        i = 0;
        while (i < arr.length) {
            if (arr[i] === randomnumber) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (!found) {
            arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
        }
    }
    hiragana_1 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[0]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana1").html(hiragana_1);
    hiragana_2 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[1]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana2").html(hiragana_2);
    hiragana_3 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[2]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana3").html(hiragana_3);
    hiragana_4 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[3]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana4").html(hiragana_4);
    hiragana_5 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[4]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana5").html(hiragana_5);
    hiragana_6 = "<h2>" + hiragana[arr[5]] + "</h2>";
    $("#kana6").html(hiragana_6);

    kpergunta = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    correto_secreto = hiragana[kpergunta];

    pergunta = "<h2>" + "Escolha o kana correto:" + " " + romaji[kpergunta] + "</h2>";
    $("#correto").html(pergunta);

};

 $("div.kana").click(function() {
        var text, id, correto;
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        text = $(this).text();
        if (text === correto_secreto) {
            $("#" + id).css("color", "green");
            pontos += 1;
            setTimeout(jogar, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#" + id).css("color", "red");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tested it 30 times and it's perfect so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons: First, if someone double-clicks on an item, they'll get two points. This is because, after they have clicked the correct item once, they can still click it again (or more times, if they're fast).

The second reason is the real problem. Every time that `jogar` is called, you add a `click` handler to it. Thus, the click handler can get called multiple times for a single click. The more times the click handler gets added, the more duplicates you will see.

Because you are using JQuery, you can problem just use `jquery.one()` instead of `click` and everything will work as expected: https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Oh dear! I haven't noticed the possibility to do that many clicking. I will try to follow your tip and use one.